# Is there an official Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) logo?

Tags: wpf

Is there an official Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) logo like there is for .Net and ActiveX?

Answer (score 5):

Closest you will get is Matts answer I think.. There is also this piece of art:

[image: WPF]

There is also a XAML logo out there for the filetypes:

[image: XAML logo]
<sub>(source: [zdnet.com](http://i.zdnet.com/blogs/xamllogo.jpg))</sub>

Come to think of it, even Silverlight has a nice logo. Why not make a nice logo for WPF as well :(..

[image: Silverlight]
<sub>(source: [technet.com](http://blogs.technet.com/blogfiles/seanearp/WindowsLiveWriter/WPFEisSilverlight_5784/image002_low%5B4%5D.jpg))</sub>

Ah well.. only Microsoft will know I guess :)

Comment: Silverlight probably has one because it needs to be identified by the general Internet public, much like Flash and QuickTime. Whereas a WPF app is just going to be another app the user has on their machine.

Comment: Yeah thats true.. We use wpf browser apps in our work, and an icon would be nice though ;)

Answer (score 4):

Closest I've seen is this one from [windowsclient.net](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/):

[WPF http://windowsclient.net/SiteFiles/1000/wpfsp1/wpf.png](http://windowsclient.net/SiteFiles/1000/wpfsp1/wpf.png)

Comment: Thanks. I've seen one of these too.